# Tagging a file with a version number

Tags: c#, file-io

I've developed a interop Excel application which generates various reports based on a copied template. The application has to be optimized to avoid useless routines such as updating a already up to date report.

There are 2 factors that creates the need of a very specific solution.

1. The file may manually be modified in non-automated sections (Cannot use a file HASH or Modified date)
2. I cannot afford to read inside the Excel sheet for a version number since the goal is to improve processing time by skipping files.

My idea was to use the file properties (Windows' right click properties) to add in a SQL row version or data hash.

However, so far, I haven't found a clean method to acheive this.

**So the question is**: Is there a .NET features or a highly supported / recommanded / maintained library to manage Windows' File Properties? If not, what alternative would you guys suggest?

Comment: The following are some options you have that are rather simple: (1) put version in file name (2) put text file with same name alongside that contains version.  - Can you please confirm that you thought of those and that they are not applicable in your scenario? Only than it makes sense to look into more complicated ones.

Comment: You culd play with the metadata and hide some version info in there http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/worddev/thread/f0b8eb2f-08d6-4214-a44c-946b0af6dc41

Comment: @FaddishWorm: This would require opening the file with the Office interop libraries. The OP excluded this as an option.

Comment: I cannot use the file name as manual edits will be too often lost. It's just a bad decision stability-wise in my specific situation as the files are manipulated by hands too much. As for the text file, I would rather save the last generated version into the database then the file. It would already remove the manipulation mistakes, but I'd really prefer to keep the File / Database relation smooth and flexible (as in, I delete the file because I has wrong manual data, no problem, it will just re-generate it)

Comment: Is the file always going to be on an NTFS volume? If so you could use an alternate data stream.... [Codeproject Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2670/Accessing-alternative-data-streams-of-files-on-an)

Comment: @BobVale It will. I'll look into it.

Comment: @BobVale I'm seeing a lot of security concerned posts while getting information about ADS. Should I be concerned?

Comment: There shouldn't be, it uses the regular ACL to control it.  The main security concerns are due to ADS being a good place to hide stuff (like root kits).  The only things you have to watch for is that the ADS don't survive being copied to a non NTFS volume and non ADS aware copy applications may not copy them.  If the ADS gets erased by Excel (I haven't checked) on save you could always put the data into an ADS on the parent folder.

Comment: I agree with @AmitMittal the data should be in the Excel file itself. You are already manipulating the file in the process of generating the reports, so why can't you afford to peek while you are in there?  The argument "to increase processing times", to me, should be deferred. Too many times we want to "optimize performance" before even getting it to perform.  When you design a system, there are necessary performance penalties baked into the code that are the cost of doing business. The trade-off between functionality and performance need not always tilt to speed.

Comment: @GrayFox374 So far it takes about 1 min to generate the reports on my dev machine, which is about 20 times faster then the machine it will be running on. The application is actually already live and I've received a complain from my boss. I've improved everything I could in the excel manipulation, and it helped, but not as much as needed. I need to avoid opening files I do not require to open. I've seen something about a DSOFile DLL library that would allow those modification without opening Excel, but it looks deprecated. Long lifespan of the application is a must.

Comment: I've also Threaded the generation while I was working to improve it to at least make it more fluid while it's doing it's work (and it helps me notice improvements in the generation speed)

Comment: @BobVale Seems to work well. Tested on Excel file. Modified the file and saved within Excel, ADS still there. Renamed the file, stil there. Copied the file, ADS followed as it's own instance. This will be perfect for my situation. Thanks a lot. Please copy your solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is only ever going to stored on an NTFS volume then you can use an [Alternate Data Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is a Library on Codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2670/Accessing-alternative-data-streams-of-files-on-an) that lets you use them from a .Net project

The only things you have to watch for is that the ADS don't survive being copied to a non NTFS volume and non ADS aware copy applications may not copy them

Comment: Heh, that's actually the lib I used after your comment :) Thanks a lot. I've just finished implementing it and it works perfectly (beside one slight ugly part caused by File.Copy on network drives causing delay.... had to do a try catch loop until the IO exception passes)